# String problem: remove patterns, "//, "///, "////, at the end of the string

Tags: r, stringr

I have a column with might contain "//" at the end. By it might be a single "/" or it might be three or more. How can I remove slashes at the end of the strings?

```r
df <- structure(list(hej = c("UXCG40///", "UXCD00///", "UXCD00///", 
                             "UXCC77///", "UXCC77///", "UXCA00///", "UXCD00///", "UXCC00/UXCD00//", 
                             "UXCD00///", "UXCC00/UXCD00//", "UXCA00///", "UXCC00///", "UXCG40///", 
                             "UXCC00/UXCD00//", "UXCE30///", "UXCD00///", "UXCD00///", "UXCC00///", 
                             "UXCA00///")), row.names = c(NA, -19L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                               "data.frame"))



print(df[5: 19, ])
#>  [1] "UXCC77///"       "UXCA00///"       "UXCD00///"      
#>  [4] "UXCC00/UXCD00//" "UXCD00///"       "UXCC00/UXCD00//"
#>  [7] "UXCA00///"       "UXCC00///"       "UXCG40///"      
#> [10] "UXCC00/UXCD00//" "UXCE30///"       "UXCD00///"      
#> [13] "UXCD00///"       "UXCC00///"       "UXCA00///"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just specify the `+` which implies one or more matching characters. In this case, it is `/` and also specify the position `$` (metacharacter for end of string) - in that way, it wouldn't match the `/` at any other location

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 <- df %>%
          mutate(hej = str_remove(hej, "/+$"))    

df1
# A tibble: 19 x 1
#   hej          
#   <chr>        
# 1 UXCG40       
# 2 UXCD00       
# 3 UXCD00       
# 4 UXCC77       
# 5 UXCC77       
# 6 UXCA00       
# 7 UXCD00       
# 8 UXCC00/UXCD00
# 9 UXCD00       
#10 UXCC00/UXCD00
#11 UXCA00       
#12 UXCC00       
#13 UXCG40       
#14 UXCC00/UXCD00
#15 UXCE30       
#16 UXCD00       
#17 UXCD00       
#18 UXCC00       
#19 UXCA00
```

---

In `base R`, it would be `sub`

```
df$hej <- sub("/+$", "", df$hej)
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to `sub`, the dedicated function `trimws` (which calls `sub` internally) can be used for exactly this purpose:

```r
trimws(c("UXCG40", "UXCG40/", "UXCG40///", "UXCC00/UXCD00//"), which = "right", whitespace = "/")
#> [1] "UXCG40"        "UXCG40"        "UXCG40"        "UXCC00/UXCD00"
```